# Spring data neo4j does not initialize objects annotated with @Relationship

Tags: kotlin, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have a location model like this (presenting an equivalent mock of proprietary model, ommited auto-generated id and some other fields):

```java
@NodeEntity
class Space: Location() {
    @field:Relationship(type = "SUBLOCATED_IN", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING) var subLocation: SubLocation? = null
}
```

```java
@NodeEntity
abstract class SubLocation: Location() {
    @field:Relationship(type = "LOCATED_IN", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING) var locatedIn: Building? = null
}
```

```java
@NodeEntity
class Building: Location()
```

```java
@NodeEntity
abstract class Location {
    var name: String? = null
    var city: String? = null
    var country: String? = null
}
```

A `SubLocation` is an abstract for a few different concrete classes like `Office`, `Desk`, `Room`, etc. which implementation is irrelevant. The `Location` is used e.g. in `Person` class:

```java
@NodeEntity
class Person(
    var name: String,
    @JsonIgnore @Relationship(type = "WORKS_IN", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    var location: Location? = null
)
```

When I have a subgraph like `Person`->`Room`(`SubLocation`)->`Building` everything works like a charm. I'm querying via the `Neo4jRepository` interface and it yields a `Person` object with `location` (**`Person`->`SubLocation`**) as well as `locatedIn` (**`SubLocation`->`Building`**) properly set:

```java
interface PersonRepository: Neo4jRepository<Person, Long> {
    @Depth(5) // exaggerated for test purposes
    fun findAllByName(name: String): List<Person>
}
```

The problem reveals when I have a subgraph like

`Person`-> **`Space`** -> `Room`(`SubLocation`)->`Building`

and when I query using the same repository method I get only the first level of relations mapped to objects. `Person` object has `location` set to `Space` proprely, but `Space` has `subLocation` set to `null`.

I'm using the newest versions of: `spring-data-neo4j -> 5.1.6.RELEASE` and `neo4j-ogm-core -> 3.1.8` and `neo4j:3.5.3`.

**TL;DR:**

`spring-data-neo4j` does not automatically map `@Relationship` annotated field with abstract class type to a concrete object, `null` is assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is solvable by custom `@Query`:

```java
interface PersonRepository: Neo4jRepository<Person, Long> {
    @Query(""""
        MATCH g=(:Person)-[*1..3]->(:Building)
        RETURN g
    """")
    fun findAllByName(name: String): List<Person>
}
```